# Showing images from local app directory in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to show images from local app directory in Flutter. Saving the image works well. After I take a picture I save the final directory string in the database. Then I try to show all images in a Listview.

How I save images:

```
Future<void> _addPictureToGallery() async {
      final picker = ImagePicker();
      final imageFile =
          await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxWidth: 600);

      final appDir = await syspath.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);

      final savedImage =
          File(imageFile.path).copy('${appDir.path}/albums/$albumID/$fileName');

      picturesData.add(Picture(
          album: albumID,
          path: '${appDir.path}/albums/$albumID/$fileName'.toString(),
          timestamp: Timestamp.now()));
    }
```

First I copy the image to the app directory. Then I save the image path in the database.

After that I want to show all images with `Image.file`. But this step is not working.

**My code**

```
body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: picturesData.getAll(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                  snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Image.file(File(snapshot.data[index].path));
                    });
              }
            }),
      ),
```

The `snapshot.data[index].path` variable is the correct image path, I´ve checked this by output a Text widget with this variable. (For example: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/884283C4-FC82-4DDB-B0C2-43BABC2D660E/Documents/albums/6/image_picker_ACF15E5E-FDB1-4B65-A56C-5B707F5EEECB-34279-00002AD6A23369E1.jpg`

But if I try to output an image with this variable, I just get the error:
`Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/884283C4-FC82-4DDB-B0C2-43BABC2D660E/Documents/albums/6/image_picker_ACF15E5E-FDB1-4B65-A56C-5B707F5EEECB-34279-00002AD6A23369E1.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

But the image exists and the path is correct..... What could be the issue here?

Comment: *On Android, this may require the android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.* referenced from [Image.file docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html) . Maybe this can be the issue.

Comment: I try it on a real iOS device..are there needed also permissions?

Comment: No. For iOS docs don't mention anything as such.

Comment: Found this [related issue on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26277)

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but also there is no solution yet.. :/

Comment: Yes, no fix mentioned yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Image.asset` no need for `File`:

```
  String _path = "";

  Future<void> _addPictureToGallery() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final imageFile =
        await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 600);

    setState(() {
      _path = '${imageFile.path}';
    });
  }

//build

return  _path.isNotEmpty ? Image.asset(_path) : Container();
```

Comment: `Unable to load asset: /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE42E172-AC16-43FF-959A-6F2D17143416/data/Containers/Data/Application/7DE77FB9-3C97-4E6C-A5C3-04DEA21475ED/Documents/albums/4/image_picker_A455D246-C655-4CDA-B0CE-F1CBABD8409D-27000-000010590C7A6B67.jpg`